# Best way to create mobile menu?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a template that I am trying to convert into a custom theme and it contains a mobile menu that is a duplicate of the main menu.

What is the best way to tackle this with the least amount of duplication?

I tried to create a **menu--main.html.twig** file and repeated 2 menus in one file.  It looked liked it worked at first until my menu contains submenus and then some weird behavior where it nested both menus into the below menu.  I would like to avoid creating a separate mobile menu in the admin dashboard and manually adding new links if created, but if that is the best way then I can handle it.  Just looking for other opinions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework? I suggest you research either of these 2 frameworks and you will find that you can accomplish your goal using either one.

Here is a little background. Basically they are just a javascript file and css file. The javascript file has code for a ton of common/widely used features and built to be mobile responsive.
All you have to do is assign your divs a specific class name and they will get a certain functionality. You can find the class names that you need to use on their documentation page.

In Drupal, you can use the [Boostrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) or [Zurb Foundation theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_foundation) to build on top off. These themes have done some of the work for you. Ex: assign all the buttons the proper button classes using a preprocess function.

Here are specific tutorials regarding your question:

[Bootstrap 3 Tutorials - #2 - Responsive Collapsing Navbar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4)

[Zurb Foundation | Top-Bar Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSP0MELy2DU)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap Framework then take the Theme [Aegan](https://www.drupal.org/project/aegan) for example, In this theme it well handle the multi-level menu and also would support for mobile menu, Take it as inspiration it would help to create better menu for you.

And also see my [blog](https://knackforge.com/blog/pathirakaliappan/create-multi-level-bootstrap-menu-in-Drupal-8) it explain to create mobile multi-level menu in drupal 8